# Basic job control: stop a job, add a job onto the stack, and `fg`

Tags: bash, job-control, jobs

Job control is probably my favorite thing about Linux. I find myself, often, starting a computationally demanding process that basically renders a computer unusable for up to days at a time, and being thankful that there is always `CTRL-Z` and `fg`, in case I need to use that particular computer during that particular time period.

Sometimes, however, I want to insert a job onto the job stack. I've never figured out how to do that.

I'm using `bash`.

It would probably look something like:

```
$ ./reallybigjob
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 reallybigjob
$ (stuff I don't know) && ./otherbigjob
$ fg
```

Comment: There is no "stack". Are you trying to "pause" reallybigjob, start otherbigjob, and have reallybigjob automatically "resume" when otherbigjob is done?

Comment: `at` (and `atq`) could be handy here, but I'm not entirely sure if two commands run `at now` run *after each other*... ([some examples](http://www.linux-support.com/cms/en/component/content/article/127-delayed-job-execution-on-linux))

Comment: I want to resume reallybigjob and enter otherbigjob immediately following the termination of reallybigjob. the same command would also allow me to add 100 jobs in a predetermined sequence, resume reallybigjob, then enter otherbigjob001, otherbigjob002, etc..

Comment: Related: [How can I queue processes?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20952)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no job stack, each job is handled independently.

You can do `fg; otherbigjob`. That will put `reallybigjob` back to the foreground, then when the `fg` command stops run `otherbigjob`. This isn't the same thing as queuing `otherbigjob` for execution after the first job: if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then `otherbigjob` starts immediately. If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then `reallybigjob` is killed. You can't leave `otherbigjob` in the background and queue another job after it.

If the jobs are CPU-intensive, then the `batch` utility can let you schedule the next job when the CPU isn't busy.

Comment: a semicolon. how simple. i knew there would be a way to do the thing i needed to do. thank you. i will definitely also use batch at some point.

Answer (score 3):

You can have more than one job running or paused in the background:

```
$ ./reallybigjob &
[1] 873
$ ./otherbigjob &
[2] 875
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 ./reallybigjob &
[2]+  Running                 ./otherbigjob &
$ fg 1
./reallybigjob
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./reallybigjob
$ fg 2
./otherbigjob
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 ./otherbigjob
$ jobs
[1]-  Stopped                 ./reallybigjob
[2]+  Stopped                 ./otherbigjob
$bg 1
[1]- ./reallybigjob &
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 ./reallybigjob &
[2]+  Stopped                 ./otherbigjob
$
```