# Modify background jobs and/or notify on job completion post-launch

Tags: bash, background-process, jobs

I would like to be able to somehow modify a running command and/or get notified when a running command completes *after* it has been started.

Normally, when I know a command is going to take a long time, I will preemptively set something up for a notify:

```
./takes_long_time && touch done
```

or

```
./takes_long_time; touch done
```

My question is if `./takes_long_time` was executed without the `touch`, is there a way I can go back and add it without restarting `./takes_long_time`?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a bit more searching, I found [the solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/basic-job-control-stop-a-job-add-a-job-onto-the-stack-and-fg):

```
$ ./takes_long_time
<ctrl-z>
[1]+  Stopped ./takes_long_time

$ fg && touch done
```

There are some caveats depending on how you use this (`fg; touch done` may produce undesirable results, see linked post).

Also, you cannot do things like add a pipeline (`fg | grep something`), though this is an understandable limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have to put the   `./takes_long_time`  in the background;

instead of

```
./takes_long_time && touch done
```

do

```
./takes_long_time &
```

This will place `./takes_long_time` in the background to run. Afterwards you can execute `./takes_long_time`. Hence, there will be two of these process running in the background.

An untraditional way of being notified of whether a command is finished can be like

```
if command_line; then 
    echo "It is done"
fi
```

example

```
if sleep 5; then 
echo "Finish sleeping for 5 seconds"
fi
```