# Command for "wait for the job to finish and then begin another job"?

Tags: bash, job-control, jobs

*Without knowing ahead of time that I'll want to do this*, is it possible to wait for a job to finish and automatically begin executing another one?

For example, I jump into a tmux session and execute `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.  Then I create a new pane and begin doing something, only to realize I need another package on my system I don't currently have.  I have to wait for my update/upgrade process to finish, but it's chugging away and I don't want to have to wait for it, especially since I could be doing something else while it's going, rather than having to wait for it.

I'd be fine with `^Z` and `bg`-ing the job, but my question is, is there a way to insert a job after that job is finished, so that I can `&& sudo apt install tree` for example?

EDIT: this question is different from the linked question and answer, I think, because `job1 && job2` `^Z` `fg; echo "done"` will see `echo "done"` executed after `job1` finishes: `job2` apparently gets discarded.  The way around it is to use a semicolon between `job1` and `job2`, but that's not a great solution for me.

Comment: FWIW, you can always stop the output of the command1 with ^S, blindly enter command2 followed by a newline, and then press ^Q.  When command1 will finish, command2 will be executed. I'm not expecting you to like this solution ;-)

Comment: @mosvy only if `command1` won’t read its input any more ;-).

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no better solution than that given in [Basic job control: stop a job, add a job onto the stack, and `fg`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30228/86440), but as you point out, that fails when used with `&&` (because the command placed in the background “exits” with a non-zero status code), and won’t always have the desired effect with compound commands anyway (the currently-running command is placed in the background, and following commands are run immediately).

For this particular use-case, there is a solution — you can use Diomidis Spinellis’ [`lockf.py`](https://gist.github.com/dspinellis/eb924c195206f57e896d026dbe14befa) to create a queue of commands waiting for the current `apt` command to finish:

```
lockf /var/lib/apt/lock apt install tree
```

This can be generalised to any command whose completion is externally observable in a predictable manner.

The queue is unordered, and can cause issues — if you run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

and queue an installation while `apt update` is running, you might end up with `apt install` running after `apt update`, and `apt upgrade` failing because it can’t get the lock.

Comment: I don't think that that python script does anything beyond the flock(1) utility from linux (except for opening the file in write mode, why?) or that the flock(2) system call guarantees any order in which the waiting processes will be unlocked.

Comment: The difference between `lockf.py` and `flock(1)` is that the former uses `fcntl(2)` *via* `lockf(3)` (hence the name, and the requirement to open the file in write mode); `apt` itself uses `fcntl`. But yes, the queue is unordered.

Comment: sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `flock(1)` utility from Linux (or the `lockf.py` script from the other [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515633/308316), which is similar in this respect) does not guarantee that the "queued" commands will be run in the order in which they were submitted.

```
$ sh -c 'for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do sleep .1; flock / sh -c "echo $i; sleep .3" & done; wait'
1
2
3
5
4
...
```

A silly "solution" for creating a job queue could be something like:

```
$ (echo > jobq; tail -f jobq | sh) &
[2] 6641
$ echo echo 1 >> jobq
1
$ echo echo 2 >> jobq
$ 2
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [task-spooler](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/task-spooler) (`tsp` is not `ts`) to execute a multiples `apt` commands:

```
tsp apt command 1 -y
```

Then use `-d` option to add second `apt` command to the queue list:

```
tsp -d apt command 2 -y
```

use `tsp` to check the stat of the list.

[man tsp](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/task-spooler/tsp.1.en.html):

> `ts` will run by default a per user unix task queue. The user can add commands to the queue, watch that queue at any moment, and look at the task results (actually, standard output and exit error).
>
> `-d`
>
> Run the command only if the command before finished well (errorlevel = 0). This new task enqueued depends on the result of the previous command. If the task is not run, it is considered as failed for further dependencies.

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to know ahead of time that I'll want to insert a job into the queue?

Answer (score 0):

If you get into the habit of always doing your update/upgrade is braces,

```
( sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade )
```

then job control correctly suspends the sub-process allowing you to type

```
fg ; echo "Example new command"
```

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, but there's no reason for me to do that unless I know I'm going to want to execute another command afterwards, in which case I wouldn't need to do this. That's why in my question, I mentioned not foreseeing needing to append a command at the outset. Also, I can't generalize this solution, since I'd just end up habitually running all of my commands in subshells on the off chance I want to append something. I appreciate you taking the time to contribute though, thank you.